# Uyghur Arabic scripts are rendered incorrectly in firefox web browser

Tags: firefox, display, ubuntu-font-family

Previously, Uyghur scripts are very normal in browsers but not now. The characters are not connected properly. The space between them is obvious. Besides that, the characters didn't change their shape when they are in the middle of the other characters. It is kind of like that "م ال ى"

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the tts-mscorefonts are installed. Try to remove them from the system.

```
sudo apt-get remove ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```